# Referencing common styles in user controls for reference library

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two WPF controls which deal with display of object data in data grids.  These controls are very similar, so I want to take the styles defined in both of them and put them into a common location.

I have seen that you can use a ResourceDictionary and reference the dictionary in the App.xaml, but this is a library module and I don't have an App.xaml.

I tried using

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="filename.xaml"/>
```

but I get a runtime XamlParseException saying it can't find the file.

So the question is how do I tell the User Control XAML to get the styles out of the ResourceDictionary that I created (which happens to be in a difference path location in the same project).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, filename has to be relative path to the resource.xaml.  Did not realize that until I stepped away and came back to it.